# Change the color of the radio button border on form submit in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, radio-button, required

I have a requirement that i have to change the Border-color of the radio button to Red when form is submitted without any value

I created a custom radio button control with "required" keyword

```
 <input type="radio" id="test1" name="{{'valee' + i + j}}" [(ngModel)]="entity.test" [value]="true" #dept_multimediatransfer="ngModel" required>
                                Oui
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <input type="radio" id="test2" name="{{'valee' + i + j}}" [(ngModel)]="entity.test" [value]="false" #dept_multimediatransfer="ngModel" required>
                                Non

input[type="radio"] {
    /* remove standard background appearance */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    /* create custom radiobutton appearance */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 2px;
    /* background-color only for content */
    background-clip: content-box;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    // background-color: #e7e6e7;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* appearance for checked radiobutton */
input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background-color: #4A4A4A;
}

css:
 input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.field-control), select.ng-invalid.ng-touched, p-calendar.ng-invalid.ng-touched > span, input.master-invalid:not(.field-control) {
        border: solid 1px red;
    }
```

it working fine in chrome but not working in IE, could someone help

Comment: Could you create [a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: If you are using HTML5, then you need to add a meta tag for it to work in IE. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">`

Comment: Doesn't help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngClass] property from Angular to add a conditional class which will add a CSS class that will give the red color to the tag or use [ngStyle] to give conditional style directly in the tag.

also, to give the condition, use a boolean variable that will be set to true once you click on the submit button and values are not entered.

Comment: The problem here is the styles are seen when you inspect but not applying